# Accessing to UIScrollView from other viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have two viewController:
 AController (UIScrollView is subview) and BController

- from AController I using presentModalViewController to BController . From BController i using dismissModalViewControllerAnimated to back to AController. But, i want set hidden for the UIScrollView from BController.

Please help me !
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use delegation, if you dont have so much expariance use in your AView viewWillAppear notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideScrollView) name:@"hideScrollView" object:nil];
```

and in your BView use:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"hideScrollView" object:nil];
```

In result i will fire hideScrollView method in AView when you can hide your scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way to do this is to use a delegation protocol. AController will be the delegate of BController. And before BController is dismissed, it can call a method of the protocol to alert AController, and AController itself while hide the scrollView.

Alternatively, you can override `-viewWillAppear`in the AController implementation file, to test if the 'self.presentedController' is a subclass of BController. If it is, you can hide the scrollView.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if ([self.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[BController class]]) {
        //hide the scroll view
    }
}
```

Also, I would suggest that you don't use `-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` unless you want to support iOS 4 and earlier: this method has been deprecated in iOS 6 and you'd better use `- dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` right away.